# quantifiers in comparatives adjectives

Tags: comparatives, quantifiers

Good morning. I'd like to ask you something. I was confused about these words. They said " a bit, a little, slightly, a lot, and much" are all intensifiers in comparative sentences. But according to my research,  it says they were quantifiers. I hope you can help me. Thank you so much! Have a great day!

Comment: Who are the 'they' who said this?

Comment: I'd say that in the context of linguistics, ***intensifiers*** and ***quantifiers*** are usually the same thing anyway. Or at least I think I can confidently say that to many laymen, (including me), ***intensifiers*** (such as "a lot") are a subset of ***quantifiers***. In which case there ought to be another subset of "quantifiers that **weaken** the primary attribute being referenced" (such as "a bit"), but I don't know what they'd be called.

Comment: Quantifiers **in** comparative adjectives??

Comment: I'd use 'quantifiers' only as a  subset of 'determiners'. He ate _a lot of_ / _some_ / _shedloads of_ ... pie.  He ate a lot of pies. //// I use 'intensifiers' and 'downtoners' to mean semantically bleached modifiers-of-adjectives and modifiers-of-adverbs. He is _extremely_ tall / _slightly deaf_. She drives _very_ fast. There are other modifiers-of-adjectives and modifiers-of-adverbs that retain semantic weight: It was _eerily_ quiet / He drives _worryingly_ fast. These usually have intensifying effect also.

Answer (score 0):

The source used in trying to make this terminology more significant is CoGEL (*A grammar of the English language, Quirk et al.*)

> **Syntactic functions of adverbs**
> **Adverb as modifier**
> **7.56** **Modifier of adjective**
>
> An adverb may premodify an adjective. Most commonly, the modifying
> adverb is a scaling device called an *intensifier*, which cooccurs with a
> gradable adjective. We first distinguish two sets of intensifiers: *amplifiers*
> and *downtoners*

[image]

> **8.1** **Intensifiers**
> The intensifier subjuncts are broadly concerned with the semantic category
> of DEGREE. It should be noted that the term'intensifier' does not refer
> only to means whereby an increase in intensification is expressed. Rather, an
> intensifying subjunct indicates a point on an abstractly conceived intensity
> scale; and the point indicated may be relatively low or relatively high.

*Classification of the intensifierss given*

- **amplifiers (boosters):** a lot , much
- **downtoners (diminishers):** a bit, a little, slightly

*Examples of use*

♦ He is much short**er**.
♦ They are a lot tall**er**.
♦ He is a bit dull.
♦ It is slightly noticeable.
♦ Some of them are a little silly.

**Note:** <s>He is much short.  They are a lot tall.</s>

In what precedes the words are adverbs as modifiers. In what follows they are adverbs as clause element adverbials; they belong to the particular class of adverbials called *subjuncts* (there are in all 4 classes: adjuncts, subjuncts, disjuncts, conjuncts).

> **8.115** **Intensifier items as quantifiers, frequentatives, duratives**
> Many items that are intensifiers are also used to denote a measure of quantity
> or of duration or of frequency in time. These intensifiers include:
>      most of the minimizers;
>      the compromisers *enough, sufficiently* ;
>      the boosters *much*, *a lot* (informal), *a good deal*, *a great deal*;
>      the diminishers *a bit* (informal), *a little*, *least*, *somewhat*, *to some extent*.
> We can therefore contrast several uses of, for example, *a lot*:
> ♦ I like them a lot. ['to a great extent' - booster intensifier]

So, here are again "a lot , much, a bit", and "a little" but as quantifiers. Naturally, "slightly" can be added to the diminishers.

*Examples of use*

♦ I paid him a lot for his work.
♦ He drinks a little.
♦ She knows very much.
♦ She liked him much.
♦ He was hurt only slightly.